# Scrape clickable link or xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, linked-list

I have this html tree in a web app:
[image]

I have scraped all the text for all the league names.

But I also need a XPATH or any indicator so that I can tell selenium: if I choose for example EFL League Two (ENG 4) in my GUI from e. g. a drop down menu, then use the corresponding xpath to choose the right league in the web app.

I have no idea how I could either extract a XPATCH from that tree nor any other solution that could be used for my scenario.

Any idea how I could fix this?

If I try to get a 'href' extracted, it prints just "None"

This is my code so far:

```
def scrape_test():

    leagues = []
    #click the dropdown menue to open the folder with all the leagues
    league_dropdown_menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/section/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[7]/div')
    league_dropdown_menu.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    
#get all league names as text
    scrape_leagues = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='with-icon' and contains(text(), '')]")
    for league in scrape_leagues:
        leagues.append(league.text)
    print('\n')

# HERE I NEED HELP! - I try to get a link/xpath for each corresponding league to use later with selenium
    scrape_leagues_xpath = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='with-icon']")
    for xpath in scrape_leagues_xpath:
        leagues.append(xpath.get_attribute('xpath')) #neither xpath, text, href is working here

    print(leagues)
```

Comment: add html as part of post not an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`li` node doesn't have `text`, `href` or `xpath` (I don't think its a valid HTML attribute). You can scrape and parse `@style`.

Try to use this approach to extract background-image URL

```
leagues.append(xpath.get_attribute('style').strip('background-image:url("').rstrip('");'))
```

Comment: exactly what i needed! Thanks!